# экранирование символа

Tags: node.js, cmd, perl

Как экранировать оператор "%" в node/cmd, OS Windows

```
my $s = "

var a = 4;
var b = 2;

if(a % b == 0){
console.log('ok');
}

console.log('done');

";

my $r = `node -e " $s "`;
print $r;
```

если заменить на любой другой, "done" - проходит

Comment: пока такое решение: my $s = " var b = new Buffer('dmFyIGEgPS...', 'base64'); eval(b.toString()); "; my $r = `node -e " $s "`; print $r; есть еще варианты?

Comment: Возможно, поможет тема https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551829/escape-percent-in-bat-file

Comment: не, это пробовалось